# How to List out .EPUB files in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, epub

I am creating an epub reader. In that I want to list out .epub files from iphone. So I want to know is there any possible way to list out the .epub files from iphone (not just from the project directory path but also anywhere else in the phone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the @rckoenes: Any files out of App bundle is not accessible,

So I retrieved .epub files like this way.

```
  NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath:bundleRoot];

    NSString *filename;

    while ((filename = [direnum nextObject] )) {


        if ([filename hasSuffix:@".epub"]) {   //change the suffix to what you are looking for


            [arrayListofEpub addObject:[filename stringByDeletingPathExtension]];


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.

Since there is no filesystem access, except the the directory with in apps sandbox.

All apps have to store the files they use with there sandbox, you tell iOS that you app can op `.epub` files. Which will allow the user to open the file from, example an email in your app.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @rckoenes, it is not possible to access the filesystem other than your app bundle.

You can access the files in your app bundle like this:

```
NSString *bundlePathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSError *error;
NSArray *bundleContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePathName error:&error];

for (NSString *currentItem in bundleContents) {
    if ([currentItem rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        int tempIndex = (int)([fileName rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].location);
        tempIndex++;
        NSString *aStrExtension = [[fileName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(tempIndex, [fileName length]-tempIndex)] lowercaseString];

        if ([aStrExtension isEqualToString:@"epub"]) {

           //Add this file to an array, to make it available for choosing and view its details
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to open ePub files saved not inside your application bundle, then you cant, you will have access only to the files inside your app sandbox